# Attempting to Add Using Flatmap and Map in Swift

Tags: swift, higher-order-functions, flatmap

I'm attempting to add after transforming a two-dimensional array into a one dimensional array using the following code in a Playground:

```
let twoDimensionalArray = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6], [12, 15, 16]]
let oneDimensionalArray = twoDimensionalArray.flatMap { $0.map { $0 += 2 } }
print(oneDimensionalArray)
```

However I receive the error:

> left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: '$0' is immutable

Also I see that the flatmap method is deprecated in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2903427-flatmap) so what should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost right. All you need is remove `=`:

```
let twoDimensionalArray = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6], [12, 15, 16]]
let oneDimensionalArray = twoDimensionalArray.flatMap { $0.map { $0 + 2 } }
print(oneDimensionalArray) // [3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8, 14, 17, 18]
```

You can apply changes to the value (`$0`) in closure by manipulating with it and something else, not by directly changing (i.e. `$0 += 2`).

Comment: I like the way you said "You can apply changes to the value ($0) in closure by manipulating with it and something else, not by directly changing (i.e. $0 += 2)." because it made the point very clear as to what I was doing wrong.